# MKPinAnnotationView custom image

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mapkit, mkpinannotationview

I would like to set a custom image instead of the normal pin on a Map. I also want it to be able to be opened and add the drop annimation for each one.

Any suggestion?

EDIT: Here is all I have

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(ActivityAnnotation *)annotation
{
    static NSString* AnnotationIdentifier = @"AnnotationIdentifier";
    MKPinAnnotationView* pinView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:AnnotationIdentifier];
    pinView.animatesDrop=YES;
    pinView.canShowCallout=YES;
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Map_Pin"];
    pinView.image = image;
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    imageView.frame = CGRectMake(-2.5,6,27,30);
    [pinView addSubview:imageView];
    UIButton* rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
    rightButton.tag = [activities indexOfObject:annotation.activity];
    [rightButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showDetails:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    pinView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;

    return pinView;
}
```

Everything works fine, but the original pin keeps getting displayed behind my default image. How can I erase it?

Answer (score 6):

Try not using MKPinAnnotationView, but instead using MKAnnotationView.  The MKPinAnnotationView shows a pins by default and only allows you to customize the color (if I'm not mistaken).  The MKAnnotationView allows for custom pin images.

Comment: Yes, but if I use a MKAnnotationView, how can I make the animatesDrop animation?

Comment: You then have to animate with a drop yourself. It is a bit annoying to calculate the top of the map coordinates, but it's a simple animation on the frame position.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/2399387  This gist is an example of how I drop  my MKAnnotationViews using custom animation.

Comment: I had the opposite question. Missed the MKPinAnnontationView.